# Is it possible to keep playing under lock screen with the MMP Player Framework video player?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When using the MediaPlayer from http://playerframework.codeplex.com/

I'm setting the `ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` to `IdleDetectionMode.Disabled`, but when the phone is locked, the video pauses. Is there any way to enable the video to keep playing?

Comment: Once I've found a 'NOTE: To exercise the app you will need a device, as I don’t think the emulator runs under lock or simulates lock.  Also, when running this, make sure your device is not attached to Zune, as that will lock media library and prevent the app from playing music (and this sample does not throw error for that).' here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx - maybe it will help, thought Ive not tested it.

Comment: I'm testing this on the device

Comment: Playing a video through the default launcher will stop it when you lock the screen and you can't get rid of it. It's a sort of OS limitation (yes, another one), but to me it makes sense.

Comment: I was not talking about the default launcher, but of the Microsoft Media Platform player